# Python Create a Dictionary of Lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Alright I searched, but I did not find an answer to my specific problem. I am creating a dictionary of lists. I have while loop creating a few lists of values as well as a name to associate with it:

```
dict = {} 
list = [1, 2]
name = key1
list = [3, 4]
name = key1
```

If the name is the same, the list will be appended to the existing set of values for the key. Here is the code I have:

```
if key in dict:
    dict[key].append(list)
else:
    dict[key] = list
```

This is the output I want:

> dictionary = {'key1': [1, 2], [3, 4]}

However I keep getting this output:

> dictionary = {'key1': [1, 2, [3, 4]]}

where the second list to the key is being put inside of the first list.

Comment: In the output you want you seem to have a key with 2 values. That's not going to happen. should it perhaps be dictionary = `{'key1': [[1, 2], [3, 4]]}` or h 2 values. That's not going to happen. should it perhaps be dictionary = `{'key1': [1, 2, 3, 4]}`

Comment: don't name your variables as `list` and `dict` as they shadow the builtin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very common error. I am fairly certain that you are doing:

`list1.append(list2)`

Instead, you want to do:

`list1.extend(list2)`

Here is a [very useful resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/python-append-vs-extend)

However, since you want `[[1,2], [3,4]]` instead of `[1,2,3,4]`, you should do:

```
if key in d1:
    d1[key].append(l1)
else:
    d1[key] = [l1]
```

Comment: That's a little better, but extend gives me:                                               dict = {[1, 2, 3, 5]}                                                                                    instead of                                                                                                         dict = {[1, 2], [3, 4]}

Comment: @MarcAlex, What do you mean by `[1,2], [3,4]`? That is not possible. A dictionary cannot have multiple values for the same key. Did you mean `[[1,2], [3,4]]`

Comment: Yeah, I guess I did mean to create a list of lists in the dictionary. So I would nee [[1, 2], [3, 4]] in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are appending a list to a list each time. You need to use extend instead. Code:

```
keys = ['name1', 'name2', 'name2', 'name1']
somelist = [1, 2, 3]
d = {}
for k in keys:
   d.setdefault(k, []).extend(somelist)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a list of list in fact, your output will look like this:

> dictionary = {'key1': [[1, 2], [3, 4]]}

To have a key associated to multiple values you could use this line:

```
dictionary.setdefault(key, []).append(a_list)
```

setdefault will associate the key to the default value `[]` if the key is not present in your dictionary.

Also you should avoid using `dict` or `list` to define your own variables, they are `built-in` and you are redefining them.

***Edit***

To make it obvious to the reader maybe this could help, its the output of an interative python session:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d.setdefault('key1', []).append([1, 2])
>>> d.setdefault('key1', []).append([3, 4])
>>> d
{'key1': [[1, 2], [3, 4]]}
```

Comment: dictionary = {} .... dictionary.setdefault("key", []).append([1,2]) .... i like this :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope not misunderstand , since dictionary = {'key1': [1, 2], [3, 4]} is poorly expressed

```
def add2dict(d, l, k):
  if not k in d:
    dict[k] = []
  d[k].append(l)

dict = {} 
add2dict(dict, [1,2], "key1")
add2dict(dict, [3,4], "key1")
```

result in dict:

> {'key1': [[1, 2], [3, 4]]}